# How to install node modules globally?

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs

I have zero experience with npm other than knowing it exists. I believe I have managed to install uglify, but I have no idea how to use it. I had until recently been using Yuicompressor which had a java cli. How can I do something similar with uglify on a Windows 7 environment?

Unless there is a step I skipped, the command line tools details the arguements, but my attempts to try such fail.

https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS

```
C:\Data\Websites\local\htdocs\b>npm install uglify-js
uglify-js@2.7.0 node_modules\uglify-js
├── uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2
├── async@0.2.10
├── source-map@0.5.6
└── yargs@3.10.0 (decamelize@1.2.0, camelcase@1.2.1, window-size@0.1.0, cliui@2.
1.0)

C:\Data\Websites\local\htdocs\b>uglify
'uglify' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Anyone care to advise?

Comment: You'll probably need a `-g`lobal install to use the CLI. You could also include the uglification in your Gulp/Grunt/whatever build workflow for repeatability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you installed the package uglify-js, to actually use it, it is: uglifyjs. So using your example, it would be something like:

```
C:\Data\Websites\local\htdocs\b>uglifyjs [ options... ] [ filename ]
```

Where options are parameters like: `--compress`, and a filename would be whatever JS file you want to uglify. e.g. `uglifyjs --compress --mangle -- input.js`

Comment: @fiprojects Did this work for you without installing it globally?

Comment: You did well to spot my error in using uglify instead of uglifyjs. It is worth mentioning that it did not work from my open dos shell as it had the old path. When I opened a new shell, uglifyjs --help gave me a related response.

Comment: @fiprojects Did you or did you not have to add the `-g` to the install?

Comment: The -g option was very helpful so I uninstalled and reinstalled. Your -g suggestion means the install can be outside my docroot directory and reachable elsewhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To run it from the command line, you have to install it globally

```
C:\Data\Websites\local\htdocs\b>npm install uglify-js -g
```

Also, the name of the executable is `uglifyjs`

```
C:\Data\Websites\local\htdocs\b>uglifyjs
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a 'Usage' section on the repo's README.

```
uglifyjs [ options... ] [ filename ]
```