# uglifyjs compresseses but does not mangle function or variable names

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs

I found a post back in 2012 that has similar problems, but it invokes uglifyjs differently

[Uglify-js doesn't mangle variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959154/uglify-js-doesnt-mangle-variable-names)

I have a Windows 7 environment, uglifyjs 2 installed via npm and post [How to install node modules globally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38661930/how-to-install-node-modules-globally)

I call uglify as follows:

```
uglifyjs --compress dead_code=true --mangle --mangle-toplevel -- x.js > x-min.js
```

My code crunches (from 127kb to 55kb) but when I open my code, I find function and variable names are original.

The browser demo tool gives the same results.

Anyone care to advise how I can obfusicate variable and function names with, or without uglify ?

Comment: What about function arguments and internal variables? Are they minimized? Uglifying public functions and variable names typically cause problems when accessing from other scripts or html. 

You can find some alternitives on the uglify website http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/.
I got really good results using jspacker which may also be an alternative: http://dean.edwards.name/packer/

Comment: this seams to be relevant for top-level names: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959154/uglify-js-doesnt-mangle-variable-names?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're mentioning using [UglifyJS2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2).

The option `--mangle-toplevel` or `-mt` comes from [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS).

There is no `--mangle-toplevel` option in [UglifyJS2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2).

In [UglifyJS2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2), to enable the mangler, you need to pass the `--mangle` or `-m` option. It accepts the following (comma-separated) options:

- toplevel
- eval

So, in your case, you'll need to use `--mangle toplevel`.

Comment: Thanks... I removed the --mangle-toplevel and instead used the --mangle toplevel and got exactly what I was looking for (results in my code crunched an additional 7k to 48k down from no mangled 55k and no compressed 127k).